# Установка системы на KVM ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kvm

Товарищи помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.
Имеется выделенный сервер на котором развернута ubuntu 20.
qemu-kvm уже поставил, остался последний шаг установка системы. В мануалах вижу как ребята с лёгкостью берут образ из локальной папки сервера например `--cdrom /kvm/iso/ubuntu-18.04.3-server-amd64.iso \`

Однако у меня нет на сервере образа *.iso, а он находится у меня на ПК, собсвенно ubuntu я установил как раз с образа который был у меня на ПК. Вот только теперь надо дать образ уже системе.
Как мне указать системе, чтобы она считала образ из Virtual Storage?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопировать на сервер нужный образ — объективная трудность, или невозможно по условию практической работы, например?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно посмотреть какие приводы вообще видны в системе.

Установим утилиту wodim:

```
apt-get install wodim
```

После устновки пишем:

```
wodim --devices
```

Должно быть что-то типа этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если ничего не нашел, то нужно перезагрузится чтобы сервер обнаружил вируальный CDROM

Таким образом cdrom тут `/dev/sg0` можно пробовать монтировать. Или приказать считывать образ прям с устройства.

Есть ещё один нюанс, возможно `/dev/sg0` является символьной ссылкой. И при попытке монтирования или чтения для установки с такого образа будет ошибка, так как символьная ссылка не является блочным устройством.

Попробуем выяснить настоящий путь так:

`ls -al /dev/cdrom*`

На выходе получите
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 3 Sep  13 13:22 /dev/cdrom -> sr0`

Это значит что при установке виртуалки обращаться к диску надо вот так `--cdrom /dev/sr0`

Готово!